# django with dotcloud: part of URL skipped

Tags: django, dotcloud

This is a Django site, migrated to Dotcloud through [this documentation](http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/tutorials/python/django/). I have an issue with my URLs: I cannot access my admin part, and the root URL that is not supposed to be matched matches ! Let me explain in detail:

```
root/
|- settings.py
|- urls.py
|- champis/
   |- urls.py
```

File `root/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^champis/', include('champis.urls')),
    (r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

File `root/champis/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('champis.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^recherche/$', 'search'),
    url(r'^glossaire/$', 'glossary'),
    url(r'^glossaire/(?P<letter>\w)/$', 'glossary'),
    url(r'^(?P<champi_name>\w+)/$', 'detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<champi_name>\w+)/(?P<photo_nb>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
)
```

So I should find my admin site at `http://server.com/admin`, and my application at `http://server.com/champis`, but this is not the case:

- `http://server.com/admin` and `http://server.com/champis` trigger a 404
- but my applications is served at `http://server.com` !

It looks like as if the `champis` part of the URL was automatically and magically added to the root URL... Do you have an explanation ? Thanks !

EDIT: extract of my `settings.py`:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

Django version is 1.4, and actually `DEBUG` is set to `True`.

Comment: Restarted server? You sure your application urls are not referred to via `ROOT_URLCONF`?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: If you have DEBUG=True what does the django output tell you? Also what version of Django are you using?

Comment: Edit added to clarify these points.

Comment: @Emmanuel when you have DEBUG=True your 404 page should give you a list of available URL patterns that django looked at. Can you post that list?  Also, have you tried ROOT_URLCONF='root.urls' ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#root-urlconf

Comment: Well, with dotcloud push you lose the `root` folder hierarchy, so you have to specify `'urls'` directly. I don't have anything exploitable in the logs: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://server.com/admin/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` from `'^admin/$'`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^champis/', include('champis.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: I just tried, but that does not remove the error. Moreover this is the standard Django configuration for the admin site.